# Why OpenSSL can't use /dev/random directly?

Tags: openssl, key-generation, entropy, random

I couldn't find the answer for the reason anywhere, even the [wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers) page doesn't explain it. This seems like using a PRNG for seeding an another PRNG. The first one <sup><sub>(/dev/random)</sub></sup> may itself be seeded by a PRNG.

I can *'understand'* why the`-rand`option can't be used directly for generating keys, but I can't see the reason for the main sources. Many people say`/dev/random`doesn't produce enough output, which is **wrong** when its entropy is fed by a daemon.

Do they consider`/dev/random`not to be a quality source?

Answer (score 19):

Reading bytes from a device can be troublesome (you have to account for syscall specificities, e.g. interrupted system calls) and can *potentially* be inefficient if reading many small chunks (a syscall has a non-negligible overhead). A custom software PRNG, *seeded* with bytes from `/dev/urandom`, gives more control over performance.

(Also, there might be a bit of [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here) syndrome here, too.)

Comment: I also start wonder why they prevent aware professionals from using a generated file of random data (assuming better quality than openssl (I recognize this is not really realistic)).

Comment: I think it's a mix of NIH and not trusting the OS to get it right. The performance issue could be fixed with relatively simply buffering instead of doing entropy gathering yourself.

Comment: @CodesInChaos : Well, in my case, I wanted to just try clrngd mixed with rngd working with rdrand. I also don't really understand what is the purpose of the large table in [/crypto/seed/seed.c](https://raw.github.com/openssl/openssl/master/crypto/seed/seed.c) of the openssl source tree.

Comment: That large table is the S-box (expanded) for the symmetric encryption algorithm SEED, specified in [RFC 4269](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4269). It is an "official" algorithm from Korea. In OpenSSL source code, the `SS[]` array is defined in `seed.c` but used in macros defined in `seed_locl.h` (which is included by `seed.c`).

Answer (score 18):

If you're asking why [`openssl rand`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/rand.html) or [`RAND_bytes()`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RAND_bytes.html) do not simply regurgitate `/dev/random` or `/dev/urandom`, it's because their function is to serve only as a PRNG, and they do exactly that:

> The `rand` command outputs num pseudo-random bytes after seeding the random number generator once.

A correctly compiled and operating OpenSSL will read 32 bytes from `/dev/urandom` where available (and unless a hardware *engine* is specified instead), and use (some or all of) this to seed a PRNG. You can confirm if `random` or `urandom` are read with `strace` on a *nix system with:

```
$ strace -xe trace=file,read,write,close openssl rand 10
[...] 
open("/dev/urandom", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
read(3, "\x26\x20\xfc\x61\x59\x81\xc9\x4d\xe5\x27\xab\xc2\x72\xb1"..., 32) = 32
close(3)                                = 0
```

As to *why* that is so, as a software library, OpenSSL cannot [generate truly random numbers directly](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/124233/why-is-it-impossible-to-produce-truly-random-numbers). The choices are to use a cryptographically secure PRNG with a good random seed (i.e. with OS harvested data from effectively random hardware events); or use a real hardware RNG. The [Hardware](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers#Hardware) section of the wiki explains how to do the latter, including how to access on-chip (Intel's RDRAND) RNG using the "engine" capability. Thomas Pornin's excellent answer here explains why a (correctly seeded, cryptographically-secure) PRNG is sufficient for most purposes: [Evaluating the entropy gathering in a PRNG](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2604/evaluating-the-entropy-gathering-in-a-prng)

If you want to be in charge of feeding random data to OpenSSL in a configurable way then using an [EGD-style](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RAND_egd.html) socket might be the easiest option. If you want to feed random numbers directly through the OpenSSL API, an [engine](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/engine.html) is the "best" option (though you can [cheat a little](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/RAND_set_rand_method.html), example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437177/force-openssls-rngs-to-return-a-repeatable-byte-sequence))

I believe OpenSSL uses [its own PRNG algorithm](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/rand.html#INTERNALS), unless you have FIPS enabled.

OpenSSL absolutely *does* use `/dev/random` when available: an excerpt from [one of the answers](https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html#USER1) in the [FAQ](https://www.openssl.org/support/faq.html):

> All OpenSSL versions try to use /dev/urandom by default; starting with version 0.9.7, OpenSSL also tries /dev/random if /dev/urandom is not available.

and the wiki page you reference:

> ### Initialization
>
> OpenSSL will attempt to seed the random number generator automatically upon instantiation by calling RAND_poll. RAND_poll seeds the random number generator using a system-specific entropy source, which is /dev/urandom on UNIX-like operating systems, and is a combination of CryptGenRandom and other sources of entropy on Windows.

---

You also asked about whether this is "seeding a PRNG from a PRNG", it depends on how strictly you define a PRNG. A defining property of a [PRNG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) is that it is *deterministic*, a PRNG has a "secret" starting point (defined by the *seed*), thereafter it is predictable (if you know that secret and the current iteration or, by extension the internal state). While a normal Linux `random` is clearly not a true "unobservable" or quantum RNG, it's not quite a normal PRNG either since its output quite quickly diverges from the deterministic values the initial seeding would result in. Conjecture aside, I think the contemporary term is a "*PRNG with input*", see this [PDF paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/338.pdf), so a qualified "yes".

Since 0.9.7 OpenSSL defaults (`DEVRANDOM` define) to using in order: `/dev/urandom`, `/dev/random`, `/dev/srandom` (with 10ms non-blocking reads) and advises:

> ```
> /* Use a random entropy pool device. Linux, FreeBSD and OpenBSD
>  * have this. Use /dev/urandom if you can as /dev/random may block
>  * if it runs out of random entries.  */
> ```

(OpenSSL-1.0.1e `crypt/rand/rand_unix.c`)

The contents of "`random`" should be used sparingly because it comes with some implied quality and is rate-limited. While `urandom` won't block, it's implied that its quality degrades with use. (At least on Linux, `urandom` is different on other platforms.)

Finally, some ancient history... OpenSSL is derived from *SSLeay* (OpenSSL was born at v0.9.0), and SSLeay (0.1 released April 1995) pre-dates commonly available OS managed (P)RNG. Linux was [the first to get a `random` device](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/5/16/300) in [v1.3.30](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/random.4.html) in 1994, followed by [FreeBSD 2.2](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=random&apropos=0&sektion=4&manpath=FreeBSD+2.2.1-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) in 1995. The `RAND_bytes()` PRNG dates from this time, so it's interesting to see in the documentation
(`doc/rand.doc` from 0.5.1b):

> ```
> First up I will state the things I believe I need for a good RNG.
> 1) A good hashing algorithm to mix things up and to convert the RNG 'state'
>    to random numbers.
> 2) An initial source of random 'state'.
> 3) The state should be very large. [...snip...]
> ```

which is followed by further discussion and a prescient summary:

> ```
> So of the points raised, only 2 is not addressed, but sources of random data 
> will always be a problem.
> ```

SSLeay first gained `/dev/random` support in version 0.5.3 (probably early 1996, change logs are a bit vague). Prior to that the PID, UID, timestamp and AFAICT, whatever was on the stack had to suffice. So `RAND_bytes()` was always a PRNG because that's a fast and portable solution. It uses what ever it can scavenge to seed the PRNG to give a useful quantity of random data, including OS provided randomness. When there's a hardware specific alternative to a PRNG, then a crypto engine can provide this functionality.

With regard to the behaviour of `-rand` I assume you mean when used with something like "`openssl genrsa 2028`". It probably just behaves this way because a moderate but indeterminate amount of random data is required (numbers are generated at random and tested for primality, a pair are needed) and the alternative was never considered useful (roughly 10-40 kiB of truly random data, as an educated guess).

Comment: `and the alternative was never considered useful (roughly 10-40 kiB of truly random data, as an educated guess).`In my case, I have 1Mb coming from /dev/random mostely seeded with clrngd and keyboard *(19ko were seeded by RDRAND)*. I recognize this not true randomness but It would maybe better than openssl RNG *(please correct me if I'm wrong)*.

Comment: Great summary, just one annoying nitpick - /dev/random is only scarce on entropy shortly after machine boot. Once it has collected enough entropy, it will stretch it out using hashing to last for centuries.

Comment: @RomanPlášil not if it’s kept seeded through something like ᴄʟʀɴɢᴅ… In that case it’s as fast as `/dev/urandom` with the advantage of using much more raw entropy.

Answer (score 2):

In general, reasons to not use the random source directly as presented include:

- You may not require as many bits of entropy as you need bits.  In this case, you can use the random bits to seed a pseudorandom number generator.  This is most important when entropy is scarce (this constraint is becoming less relevant over time as dedicated hardware entropy sources become more common).
- You do not want to trust that the random source is random.  `/dev/urandom` in particular is not trustworthy because in guaranteeing that it wiill not block on low-entropy conditions, it fails to guarantee that the output is actually random.  The manpage `man 4 urandom` has more information on this, including a cryptic allusion to an attack some government body may or may not have predicated on this condition.  Suitability tests can be conducted on this data, or it can be mutated in some way to concentrate entropy, or different sources can be combined.
- You wish to guarantee that a particular method for generating random numbers was used.  This allows you to comply with any standard mandating this without having to rely on the Linux kernel developers to do it for you.

Consider also the concept of effective key size (the base-2 logarithm of the number of iterations of some optimal algorithm for breaking the key given some known item encrypted with it).  There is obviously no purpose in consuming more bits of entropy than the effective key size, and doing so only depletes the entropy pool.

Comment: Nice! but i would prefer hearing an 'official' answer.

Comment: I don't think one exists.  It is an open-source project after all.  Perhaps search their mailing list archives?

Comment: I tried everything, but I am not a good finder for mail archives... Well, I don't understand the fact that open-source would be associated with decisions without reasons than proprietary.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Falcon's excellent answer:

```
[colin@localhost ~]$ time dd if=/dev/random of=/dev/null iflag=fullblock count=10 bs=32
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
320 bytes (320 B) copied, 32.0067 s, 0.0 kB/s
0.00user 0.00system 0:32.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3104maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+249minor)pagefaults 0swaps

[colin@localhost ~]$ time dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null iflag=fullblock count=10 bs=32
10+0 records in
10+0 records out
320 bytes (320 B) copied, 0.000289421 s, 1.1 MB/s
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 3072maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+247minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

/dev/random might be very random, but its very, very slow!

Comment: You didn't read the comments I posted on [mr.spuratic](http://security.stackexchange.com/users/18555/mr-spuratic) AT ALL! I'm using `clrngd`which allow me to get Mb of random data. Moreover If you empty the pool of /dev/random constantly, the quality of the random data will be very poor.